# Free or open source barcode/QR code reader that can take input from the computer screen

Tags: osx, barcode

I need a QR code reader that can analyze the screen and find any QR codes on it. The QR codes I encounter are usually on webpages or ebooks.

I currently have to take a screenshot and then upload to a web service which decodes the QR codes. All the Mac apps that I can find that deal with QR codes are either devoted to generating them, and not decoding them, or are designed to only read QR codes from the camera and not the screen.

Answer (score 2):

[ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) is a Cross Platform FOSS library with [Python](http://python.org) [bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar) *as well as Perl & Ruby* since it can take any image, (or a video stream), as an input it should be quite simple to write a little code that can grab the current screen/window and look for barcodes within the resulting image. Various barcodes including QR are supported.  The download includes some sample applications to get you started.

Comment: There's no mac app on the download page, only a iphone app. So I'd have to compile this source code and then write my own program, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: sorry I don't have a Mac to test and see how much work it would take.